# Two column, bulk, random access retrieval from sparse table using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm storing a relatively reasonable (~3 million) number of very small rows (the entire DB is ~300MB) in PostgreSQL.  The data is organized thus:

```
                                      Table "public.tr_rating"
  Column   |           Type           |                           Modifiers                           
-----------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 user_id   | bigint                   | not null
 place_id  | bigint                   | not null
 rating    | smallint                 | not null
 rated_at  | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 rating_id | bigint                   | not null default nextval('tr_rating_rating_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "tr_rating_rating_id_key" UNIQUE, btree (rating_id)
    "tr_rating_user_idx" btree (user_id, place_id)
```

Now, I would like to retrieve the ratings deposited over a set of places by your friends (a set of users)

The natural query I wrote is:

```
SELECT * FROM tr_rating WHERE user_id=ANY(?) AND place_id=ANY(?)
```

The size of the user_id array is ~500, while the place_id array is ~10,000

This turns into:

```
 Bitmap Heap Scan on tr_rating  (cost=2453743.43..2492013.53 rows=3627 width=34) (actual time=10174.044..10174.234 rows=1111 loops=1)
 Buffers: shared hit=27922214
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tr_rating_user_idx  (cost=0.00..2453742.53 rows=3627 width=0) (actual time=10174.031..10174.031 rows=1111 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((user_id = ANY (...) ))
         Buffers: shared hit=27922214
 Total runtime: 10279.290 ms
```

The first suspicious thing I see here is that it estimates that scanning the index for 500 users will take 2.5M disk seeks

Everything else here looks reasonable, except that it takes ten full seconds to do this!  The index (via `\di`) looks like:

```
 public | tr_rating_user_idx | index | tr_rating | 67 MB |
```

at 67 MB, I would expect it could tear through the index in a trivial amount of time, even if it has to do it sequentially.  As the buffers accounting from the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` shows, everything is already in memory (as all values other than shared_hit are zero and thus suppressed).

I have tried various combinations of `REINDEX`, `VACUUM`, `ANALYZE`, and `CLUSTER` with no measurable improvement.

Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong here, or how I could debug further?  I'm mystified; 67MB of data is a puny amount to spend so much time searching through...

For reference, the hardware is a 8-way recent Xeon with 8 15K 300GB drives in RAID-10.  Should be enough :-)

**EDIT**

Per btilly's suggestion, I tried out temporary tables:

```
 => explain analyze select * from tr_rating NATURAL JOIN user_ids NATURAL JOIN place_ids;
                                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=49133.46..49299.51 rows=3524 width=34) (actual time=13.801..15.676 rows=1111 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (place_ids.place_id = tr_rating.place_id)
   ->  Seq Scan on place_ids  (cost=0.00..59.66 rows=4066 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.619 rows=4251 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=48208.02..48208.02 rows=74035 width=34) (actual time=13.767..13.767 rows=7486 loops=1)
         Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 527kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..48208.02 rows=74035 width=34) (actual time=0.047..11.055 rows=7486 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on user_ids  (cost=0.00..31.40 rows=2140 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.399 rows=2189 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using tr_rating_user_idx on tr_rating  (cost=0.00..22.07 rows=35 width=34) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=3 loops=2189)
                     Index Cond: (tr_rating.user_id = user_ids.user_id) JOIN place_ids;
 Total runtime: 15.931 ms
```

Why is the query plan so much better when faced with temporary tables, rather than arrays?  The data is exactly the same, simply presented in a different way.  Additionally, I've measured the time to create a temporary table at running in the tens to hundreds of milliseconds, which is a pretty steep overhead to pay.  Can I continue to use the array approach, yet allow Postgres to use the hash join which is so much faster, instead?

**EDIT 2**

By creating a hash index on user_id, the runtime reduces to 250ms.  Adding another hash index to place_id reduces the runtime further to 50ms.  This is still twice as slow as using temporary tables, but the overhead of making the table negates any gains I see.  I still do not understand how doing O(500) lookups in a btree index can take ten seconds, but the hash index is unquestionably much faster.

Comment: I do not understand all but can you try JOIN (as in EDIT) without temporary tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is taking each row in the index, and then scanning through your user_id array, then if it finds it scanning through your place_id array.  That means that for 3 million rows it has to scan through 100 `user_id`s, and for each match it scans through 10,000 `place_id`s.  Those matches are individually fast, but this is a poor algorithm that could potentially result in up to 30 billion operations.

You'd be better off creating two temporary tables, giving them indexes, and doing a join.  If it does a hash join, then you'd potentially have 6 million hash lookups.  (3 million for `user_id` and 3 million for `place_id`.)

Comment: These two should be logically equivalent, shouldn't they?  Why can't the query planner do that for me?  I tried it out and indeed it is much faster.  What I do not understand is why the query plan is so bad, then...

Comment: They are logically equivalent.  This is an edge case that performs badly in a number of databases, and I don't know why none of them seriously tries to optimize it.